# ggsave in batch mode in order to automatically save all plots done

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, batch-processing

Is there a way to use ggsave in batch mode? When I say batch mode, I mean that I first plot all my plots via ggplot and then save every single plot in a specific folder. [Here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggsave.html) is an argument suggested called

```
plot=last_plot()
```

but no alternative given. Is there another option for that, like plot=all_plot()?

Comment: you can keep a list of your plots, AFAIK by itself ggplot2 only stores the last one plotted

Comment: How can I achieve to keep a list of my plots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @baptiste suggested, you can keep your plots in a list.  The following code both plots the plots (by using `print` which is necessary as otherwise the assignment to the list prevents the display of the plot), and stores them in a list, and then `lapply`s over the list to save them all as files:

```
library(ggplot2)
plots <- list()
print(plots[[1]] <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))))
print(plots[[2]] <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))))
print(plots[[3]] <- ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=runif(10), y=runif(10))))
invisible(
  lapply(
    seq_along(plots), 
    function(x) ggsave(filename=paste0("myplot", x, ".png"), plot=plots[[x]])
) )
```

Comment: This is helping me. Thank you!